# How to find the Laurent series for this function?

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried for a long time but still cannot find the Laurent Series for this function.

For f(z) = z + 1/z and |z-1| < 1

Comment: $f$ is holomorphic on $|z-1| < 1$, so its Laurent series coincide with its Taylor series.

Comment: Also, to compute the taylor series, write $$\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{1-(1-z)}$$, note that $|z-1|<1$, and use the geometric sum formula on $\frac{1}{1-(1-z)}$.